# how to fix Sort, limit and skip do not work on large amounts of data

Tags: angular, mongodb, command-line-interface

I am using pagination for mat-table and for that I have written mongoldb query as follows, but this query is not working for big data it is giving error as : Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.

```
const sort = { orderId: -1 };
collection.find({ status: { $ne: "cancel" } }).sort(sort).limit(pageSize).skip(skips).toArray(function (err, response) {});
```

I am expecting output in defending order according to `orderid`.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you need to add indexes on fields on which you want to sort. The error happens because there's no index on `orderId` that MongoDB could use and that means sorting the results in memory. That works for small amount of data but in this case it doesn't because there's a memory cap (32MB) on how much memory can be used during the operation. Try adding the following index:

```
db.my_collection.createIndex({ status: 1, orderId: -1 }, { background: true })
```

This should help you to both search based on `status` and with the sort. Notice that the index will be used effectively even though the sort is based on a non-prefix subset. That's because the first part of the query includes an equality comparison on the first key. More at [Use Indexes to Sort Query Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#use-indexes-to-sort-query-results).